# Wrap async lambda to the async method

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to wrap my `Operations Contracts` to the try-catch block. The problem is that my EF context destroyed in the same time scope. I guess the problem compiler doesn't know what to do properly. Also my catch block doesn't handle any exceptions. Sorry for my English, I hope my code show what I mean:

```
private static async Task<T> SurroundWithTryCatch<T>(Action t, T response) where T : BaseResponse 
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(t);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Errors.Add(e.Message);
    }
    return response;
}

public async Task<CreateResponse> CreateAsync(CreateRequest request)
{
    var response = new CreateResponse();
    return await SurroundWithTryCatch(async delegate
    {
        var newUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = request.UserName, Email = request.Email };
        await Database.UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser, request.Password);
        //Some another logic...
        await Database.CommitAsync();
    }, response);
}
```

The problem in the second line of `CreateAsync` method. `UserManager` was cleaned by GC earlier. So I have `ObjectDisposedException`. `Database` is the `IUnitOfWork` implementation and injected by `Autofac`.

Comment: Try replacing `SurroundWithTryCatch<T>(Action t, T response)` with `SurroundWithTryCatch<T>(Func<Task> t, T response)` and `return await SurroundWithTryCatch(async delegate` with `return await SurroundWithTryCatch(async () => `

Comment: @YacoubMassad Thank you for the fast reply! It works!! I struggled with it two o'clock or more. Could you explain what's going on and post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're breaking the `await` chain - `t` no longer returns a task. Since you no longer have a task, the execution will continue after the first `await`, rather than after the whole method is done. Think of `await` as `return` - if you don't return (and `await`/wait for) a Task, you lose your chance at synchronization.

Instead, you want to pass `Func<Task>`, and await it directly:

```
private static async Task<T> SurroundWithTryCatch<T>(Func<Task> t, T response) where T : BaseResponse 
{
    try
    {
        await t();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Errors.Add(e.Message);
    }
    return response;
}

public async Task<CreateResponse> CreateAsync(CreateRequest request)
{
    var response = new CreateResponse();
    return await SurroundWithTryCatch(async () =>
    {
        var newUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = request.UserName, Email = request.Email };
        await Database.UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser, request.Password);
        //Some another logic...
        await Database.CommitAsync();
    }, response);
}
```

`Task.Run` also works, but you probably don't want that anyway - your code is asynchronous, and (a guess) you're running in a ASP.NET request, so there's no benefit to launching a task just to wait on the result of another task. `Task.Run` is used for doing CPU work in a separate thread, something you usually want to avoid in ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my life for today!

Comment: Can I make the same thing if my `T` is premitive type?

Comment: I have an idea to wrap primitive types, but may be the better way exists.

Comment: @user3818229 I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "primitive type". In general, generics work with any types you want; if you want to do something a bit more specific, you use generic type constrains (as you have here) or casting.

Comment: I mean int, float, etc. The reference is losing if I do the same thing without wrapper.

Comment: @user3818229 So you mean value-types? Wrapping them works fine with generics. The trick is to make sure you're modifying the shared value, and not the copied value (value-types are passed by value to methods, so they always create a copy). One way to do this is to use `ref T`, another is to create your own wrapper class.